# How can I change textview after clicking on active and deactive buttons in my program?

Tags: android, textview, android-button

I have two buttons naming "Active" and "Deactive" and a TextView. when I click on "Active" button it must send an SMS containing "CMDSAD_ON"message to a phonenumber, and set "Enable" to my TextView and when clicking on "Deactive" button, it must send "CMD_OFF" and set "Disable" to the same TextView.

But when I run it, it only sets "disable" to the textview and it won't change whenever I click the buttons and it even set it before sending the SMS. I don't you how I can solve its problems.
Thanks

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //intent to filter for SS message received.
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

       // Button2 is the id of "Active button" and Button4 is the id   of "Deactive button".

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button2:

                String mymsg = "CMDSAD_ON";
                String thenumber = "916722";
                sendMsg (thenumber, mymsg);


            case R.id.button4:
                String msg = "CMDSAD_OFF";
                String phonenumber = "916722";
                sendNackMsg(phonenumber, msg);

            default:
            }}
```

and sendNackMsg function is similar to sendMsg except the last lind which change the textview to "disable"( -> Textstatus.setText("disable");)

```
public void sendMsg (String thenumber, String mymsg){
        String SENT = "Message sent";
        String DELIVERED = "Message delivered";


        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        Context curContext = this.getApplicationContext();

        PendingIntent sentPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext,
                0, new Intent("SENT"), 0);

        curContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Generic failure.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: No service (possibly, no SIM-card).",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Null PDU.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Radio off (possibly, Airplane mode enabled in Settings).",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter("SENT"));

        PendingIntent deliveredPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext,
                0, new Intent("DELIVERED"), 0);

        curContext.registerReceiver(
                new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode()) {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Delivered.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Delivered: Canceled.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter("DELIVERED"));

        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) &&
                !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, your device probably can't send SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("9167227450", null, "CMDSAD_ON_1234", sentPending, deliveredPending);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView Textstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textstatus);
        Textstatus.setText("enable");}
    }


public void sendNackMsg(String phonenumber, String msg) {
        String SENT = "Message sent";
        String DELIVERED = "Message delivered";


        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        Context curContext = this.getApplicationContext();

        PendingIntent sentPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext,
                0, new Intent("SENT"), 0);

        curContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Generic failure.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: No service (possibly, no SIM-card).",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Null PDU.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Sent: Radio off (possibly, Airplane mode enabled in Settings).",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter("SENT"));

        PendingIntent deliveredPending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(curContext,
                0, new Intent("DELIVERED"), 0);

        curContext.registerReceiver(
                new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode()) {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Delivered.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Delivered: Canceled.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter("DELIVERED"));

        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY) &&
                !pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, your device probably can't send SMS...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("09167227450", null, "CMDSAD_OFF_1234", sentPending, deliveredPending);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            TextView Textstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textstatus);
            Textstatus.setText(disable);}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your are setting a fixed text on Both buttons click

Use this condition on your buttonOnCLick and apply `break;` statement after all of  your button click.

Use same as these condition on your both button click and just change this

```
 String mymsg = "CMDSAD_ON";
    String thenumber = "916722";
    sendMsg (thenumber, mymsg);
```

On Your `button4` Click

```
       String msg = "CMDSAD_OFF";
            String phonenumber = "916722";
            sendNackMsg(phonenumber, msg);
```

Replace your message code as you do before in both conditions this is for `button2` click

```
    if(myTargetButton.getText().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("active")){

    myTargetButton.setText("Disable")
    String mymsg = "CMDSAD_ON";
    String thenumber = "916722";
    sendMsg (thenumber, mymsg);

    }else if(myTargetButton.getText().toString.equalsIgnoreCase("Disable")){

    myTargetButton.setText("Enable")
    String mymsg = "CMDSAD_ON";
    String thenumber = "916722";
    sendMsg (thenumber, mymsg);

    }



 TextView Textstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textstatus);
    Textstatus.setText("فعال");}
```

Change it and use text from your method like:

```
TextView Textstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textstatus);
        Textstatus.setText(mymsg);}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks I changed it but the result is the same:(

Comment: I added the rest of my code to my question. Any suggestions or advice  would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply... Sorry that i didn't get what you meant,ّI am new to android, would you please write your code more simply?

Comment: @RozeWinslet Check my answer hope your problem fixed by this

Comment: Thanks... but in this case none of the buttons are clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You did not apply `break` statement on your onClick. That's why it always goes throw your last case and set disable to your TextView. Check this :

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button2:

            String mymsg = "CMDSAD_ON";
            String thenumber = "916722";
            sendMsg (thenumber, mymsg);
            break;

        case R.id.button4:
            String msg = "CMDSAD_OFF";
            String phonenumber = "916722";
            sendNackMsg(phonenumber, msg);
            break;
        default: 
            break;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your suggestion but in this case, just the "Active button" works properly and the "Deactive button" is not even clickable(when I click on it, nothing happens)